# Question about appendix about calculus of variations in Bishops' Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, calculus-of-variations

I don't understand a part in the appendix (p.704-705) about the calculus of variations (which I was unfamiliar with before reading about it in the appendix) in the book ["Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning"](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2006/01/Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006.pdf) by Bishop. Since I'm not sure how much of the preceding parts of the appendix is necessary to understand the part I don't understand, I've included all the equations which I think might be of interest, and corrected according to the [errata](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/prml-errata-1st-20110921.pdf). I've highlighted the part I don't understand in bold.

Note:
$\eta(x)$ is an arbitrary function of $x$.
$\epsilon \eta(x)$ is a small change to the function $y(x)$.

> We denote the functional derivative of $F[y]$ with respect to $y(x)$ by $\delta F/\delta y(x)$, and define it by
> the following relation:
> $$F[y(x) + \epsilon \eta(x) ] = F[y(x)] + \epsilon \int \dfrac{\delta F}{\delta y(x)} \eta(x) dx + O(\epsilon^2). \quad (D.3)$$
> Requiring that the functional be stationary with respect to small variations in the function $y(x)$ gives
> $$\int \dfrac{\delta F}{\delta y(x)}\eta(x)dx = 0. \quad (D.4)$$
> Because this must hold for an arbitrary choice of $\eta(x)$, it follows that the functional
> derivative must vanish. To see this, imagine choosing a perturbation $\eta(x)$ that is zero
> everywhere except in the neighbourhood of a point $\hat{x}$, in which case the functional
> derivative must be zero at $x=\hat{x}$. However, because this must be true for every
> choice of $\hat{x}$, the functional derivative must vanish for all values of $x$.
> Consider a functional that is defined by an integral over a function $G(y, y', x)$ that depends on both $y(x)$ and its derivative $y'(x)$ as well as having a direct dependence on $x$
> $$F[y] = \int G(y(x), y'(x), x) dx \quad (D.5)$$
> where the value of $y(x)$ is assumed to be fixed at the boundary of the region of integration (which might be at infinity). If we now consider variations in the function $y(x)$, we obtain
> $$F[y(x) + \epsilon \eta(x)] = F[y(x)] + \epsilon \int \left\{ \dfrac{\partial G}{\partial y} \eta(x) + \dfrac{\partial G}{\partial y'}\eta'(x) \right\} dx + O(\epsilon^2). \quad (D.6)$$
> We now have to cast this in the form $(D.3)$. To do so, we integrate the second term by parts **and make use of the fact that $\eta(x)$ must vanish at the boundary of the integral (because $y(x)$ is fixed at the boundary). This gives**
> $$F[y(x) + \epsilon \eta (x)] = F[y(x)] + \epsilon \int \left\{ \dfrac{\partial G}{\partial y} - \dfrac{d}{dx}\left( \dfrac{\partial G}{\partial y'} \right) \right\}\eta(x) dx + O(\epsilon^2) \quad (D.7) $$

So from what I understand the reasoning goes like this:
Integrating  $\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial y'}\eta'(x)$ by parts gives:
$$\int \left( \dfrac{\partial G}{\partial y'} \right) \eta'(x) dx = \left( \dfrac{\partial G}{\partial y'} \right) \eta(x) - \int \left(\dfrac{d}{dx} \left ( \dfrac{\partial G}{\partial y'} \right) \right)\eta(x) dx$$
By comparing $(D.7)$ to $(D.6)$, I get the understanding that
$$\left( \dfrac{\partial G}{\partial y'} \right) \eta(x) = 0 \quad (i)$$
and that this has something to do with $\eta(x)$ "vanishing at the boundary of the integral" due to $y(x)$ "being fixed at the boundary". Even if no explicit boundaries are given for the integral I guess the author implicitly assumes arbitrary boundaries for the integral. I wonder if my understanding is correct and in that case can someone elaborate on why the integral $(i)$ is equal to $0$?

Comment: I recommend you read some good book on the Calculus of Variations (like Gelfand-Fomin) to understand this. It is not a good idea to learn it from a book on Machine Learning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your integrals are evaluated on some interval, say $[a,b]$. When you perturb your function $y$ by $\varepsilon\eta(x)$ you assume that $\eta(a)=\eta(b)=0$ because you want to preserve the values of $y(a)$ and $y(b)$ (this is a particular type of variation). When you integrate by parts the non-integral term disappears because you have to evaluate it between the limits $a$ and $b$. When you combine your equations (D7) and (D6) you get the identity
$$
\int\limits_a^b\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial y'}\right)\right)\eta(x)\,dx=0
$$
which must be true **for any** $\eta$ vanishing at $a$ and $b$. This is the key. From this you conclude that
$$
\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial y'}\right)=0
$$
which is the ODE that your extremal must satisfy.

Comment: Ok! That seem to make sense. Just to make sure I understand, saying that $y(x)$ is fixed at the boundary of the integral is equivalent to saying $\eta(a) = \eta(b) = 0$? (I noticed I had mistakenly written the integral term instead of the non integral term in equation $(i)$ but you seem to have understood the question anyway)

Comment: Yes, the perturbed test function is $\tilde y(x)=y(x)+\varepsilon\eta(x)$ so if you want $\tilde y(a)=y(a)$ and $\tilde y(b)=y(b)$ you need $\eta(a)=\eta(b)=0$.